# Flutter - How to make PWA works offline Safari IOS

Tags: ios, flutter, progressive-web-apps, mobile-safari, offline

I want to create a PWA that works offline in all devices and I want to know if is possible to do it with flutter. After testing the web app examples found in the official documentation I noticed that only in Safari mobile doesn't work offline. The tested web apps were:

- https://gallery.flutter.dev/#/
- https://flutter.github.io/samples/web/simplistic_editor/
- https://flutter.github.io/samples/web/material_3_demo/

Steps to reproduce:

- open one of above web apps in IOS Safari
- install the PWA
- open it, it will work correctly with network connection
- close it, turn off your network connection and then open it again
- You will see a blank screen or something similar, it doesn't load any content

Is it possible to achieve the offline mode in Safari for IOS? I searched a lot and did not find anything. It works fine on chrome for android and chrome for desktop, I was not able to install it from chrome for IOS because there is no button to add it

Thanks in advance!

Comment: @iKK I opened an issue on the github, but no updates for now :/ https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/135426

Comment: looks like there is still no luck